# Are there multiple valid definitions for what translate, rotate and scale do?

Tags: graphics, transformation, mathematics

Are there multiple valid definitions for what translate, rotate and scale do to the 4x4 matrix?

I bring up this question, because I have a simple webgl program that draws a square and does a few translate, rotate, and scale transformations. When I originally wrote the program I was using glMatrix v0.9.5. I upgraded the glMatrix to v2.2 and now the square is in a different position and rotation.

I'm fairly certain I correctly upgraded the program to use the new version, since the program was so small to begin with.

Regardless of what is happening to my program, I'm very interested to know if translate, rotate, and scale have a single universal definition or if different graphics engines / matrix libraries can have different definitions for what the transforms do.

Further details:

No transformations (origin is at the top left corner)
[image]

The square program with the following transformations:

**translate**   x: 250, y: 250, z: 0

**rotate around Z axis**   angle: -90

[image]

Finally the square program with the following transformations:

**translate**   x: 250, y: 250, z: 0

**rotate around Z axis**   angle: -90

**translate**   x: 150, y: 0, z: 0

[image]

Comment: Are the columns and rows swapped in your two different examples?  If so, that's not really a change to the way the matrix works, but rather a change of order of operations.  Sort of.

Comment: I'm fairly certain they are not swapped. I'm doing a translate, rotate, translate, and rotate to the square and I'm getting a different result with the new version of glMatrix. But if I just do   a translate and then a rotate then both versions of glMatrix give the same result.

Comment: Would you edit your question to include your input, the operations, and the different output?

Comment: I added images of what is going on. Thank you for the interest and help

Comment: When you concatenate a transformation to the existing matrix, is there an option to prepend or append the new operation? You seem to be executing the final two transformations in the opposite order.

Comment: Looks like possibly in the previous version, the second translate (150, 0, 0) was happening in the rotated coordinate system, i.e. the x-translate would be along the world space y-axis, but now the translate is being applied in world coordinates, so the x-translate is along the x-axis.  That is strange, though - with the normal way of combining transforms by multiplying matrices, you would expect the former, i.e. the v0.9.5 behavior seems more correct.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens glMatrix does not give me an option for prepend or append

Comment: @NathanReed I came to the exact same conclusion as you. Which made me wonder if there were multiple valid definitions for how the transformations are defined

Comment: @Anton There are row-vector vs column-vector definitions, but I don't think switching between those would cause these results (and besides, it'd be very unusual for a vector math lib to switch between row-vector and column-vector - they usually pick one and stick to it). I think this is likely to be a code bug rather than a definitions issue.

Comment: Instead of or in addition to pictures, post some small code samples.  There's a bazillion simple explanations for differing output from similar input.

Answer (score 1):

I have discovered that the matrix library I am using (glMatrix) did in fact change how its mat4.translate works.

It seems that different people do have different ideas about what the transforms definitions are.

I opened up an issue on the glMatrix github [page](https://github.com/toji/gl-matrix/issues/103) where it is being discussed more for those who are interested.